# select_related or select_prefetched after calling filter()?

Tags: django, django-queryset

All the examples I see have select_related() first and then filter() call as in:

```
MyModel.objects.select_related().filter()
```

Can I do

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(my_field=my_var)
qs = qs.select_related().filter(my_foreign_key_field=another_var)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can
As you can see:

```
type(MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1))
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>

type(MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).select_related())
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>

type(MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).select_related().filter(name='test'))
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

All of them are QuerySets

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it in the shell:

```
>>> from myApp.models import Unit_type, Transaction
>>> u = Unit_type.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> t = Transaction.objects.filter(unit_type=u)
>>> t = t.select_related().filter(transaction_end_status='R')
```

It didn't give me an error and gave me a queryset with length 1.